# Подскажите, как можно уменьшить количество watchers сохранив при этом изменение нужных параметров?

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Есть таблица в которой более 1000 записей. На каждой строке таблицы есть 6 изменяемых параметров.
В итоге получаем более 6000 watchers.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Телефон</th>
            <th>Статус</th>
            <th>Коммент</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | itemFilter:this" class="{{item.trClass ? 'trClass' : ''}}">
            <td class="item-menu" ng-click="showDropdownMenu()">
                {{::item.name}}
                <ul class="dropdown-menu {{item.openMenu ? 'open' : ''}}">
                    <li class="icons text-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-app pr" target="_blank" href="#/{{::item.id}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-app gr" target="_blank" href="#/{{::item.id}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>{{::item.phone}}</td>
            <td class="status status-text">
                <div class="status" ng-repeat="status in item.statuses" data-status="{{status.status_class}}">
                    <small class="badge status-name">{{::status.name}}</small>
                    <small ng-if="status.rating != null" title="Рейтинг {{::status.rating.name}}" class="badge bg-success rating">{{::status.rating.rating}}</small>
                    <span class="status-text">
                        {{status.rating.label}} {{status.rating.in_rating[0]}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{::item.comment}}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-comment pull-right {{item.hasComments ? 'has-comment' : ''}}" ng-click="openCommentForm()">
                    <span class="fa fa-comment"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Обновление данных происходит каждые 10 секунд. Часть данных может не меняться.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть таблица в которой более 1000 записей.

*Во-первых,* точно есть такая острая необходимость демонстрировать данные не постранично? Не уверен, что пользователь, открывая вашу таблицу, очень хочет редактировать много строчек. Скорей всего вам необходимо добавить пагинирование.

*Во-вторых,* зачастую многие ваши проблемы, связанные с гридом, уже давно решены за вас. От себя рекомендую **ui-grid** (http://ui-grid.info/). Он и с большим количеством строк, если так необходимо, чувствует себя комфортно.